# why cant I bind to single actor instance (akka router) with scaldi?

Tags: akka, router, dead-letter, scaldi

I´m currently struggeling with implementing my Akka router logic using scaldi for dependency injection. Why cant I bind to a single actor instance with scaldi, since my actor is a router and I only want to have one single instance of it?
The way I came to ask this question was [another stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066821/message-goes-to-dead-letter-instead-of-sender-akka-router-scala/26069359#26069359).

My scaldi Module:

```
class DAOModule extends Module {
  bind toProvider new UserDaoWorker
  binding to new UserDaoRouter
}
```

This way only one instance is created and as soon as I inject my router multiple times it gets a dead letter actor as sender from the sender() method.

When I change the binding to...

```
binding toProvider new UserDaoRouter
```

... it works perfectly fine, but every injection means a new instance of my router. Am I right?

So how can I achieve having only a single instance of my router which is injectable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
class DAOModule extends Module {
  binding toProvider new UserDaoWorker
  binding toProvider new UserDaoRouter
  binding identifiedBy 'singletonUserRouter to {
    implicit val system = inject[ActorSystem]
    AkkaInjectable.injectActorRef[UserDaoRouter]
  }
}
```

And then in my controller:

```
val userDaoRouter = inject[ActorRef] ('singletonUserRouter)
```

I hope this will help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:
bind [UserDaoRouter] to new UserDaoRouter  ??